# Generic IP Redirect for Robots

Tags: regex, redirect, ip, url-rewriting

I help manage a few hundred websites, and we often get requests from the owners to prevent search engines from indexing their site's ip address. We then modify their redirects file to include the following (customized to their own ip addresses and domain names, of course), serving up the disallow file so it doesn't get indexed:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^127\.0\.0\.1$ [NC] 
RewriteRule robots.txt robots_disallow.txt [I,O,L]
```

This works OK, but has to be configured per ip since it's hard-coded in. How can I write a generic Rewrite condition to be run on *any* ip address entered in? I've read that you can do Regex validation, but I haven't seen a lot of documentation online telling how to do that for multiple, unknown digits.

Anyone have any advice?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably better off doing a redirect to the site's actual domain name with a 301.  This teaches the spider the correct location for the resources they are crawling. So what I would typically do is something like this right at the beginning of the rewrite rules:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.yourdomain\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.yourdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This also has the benefit of being useful to all web traffic, not just spiders. Additionally it will also takes care of directing traffic to say, yourdomain.com to www.yourdomain.com

Comment: That is a good idea, but since each site has its own domain name, it would require a change on each site individually. Also, that would interfere with our internal access to their site through an internal subdomain (ex. google.com is also accessible to us at site123.mycompany.com).

What I need is a generic rewrite I can roll to all the several hundred boxes at the same time to serve [robots_disallow.txt](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=156449) to the Google spider when it tries to index the site via ip address.

Comment: I like your idea of catching all non-domain requests instead of checking to see if the request is an ip address. How about something like this? :

`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^\.com
RewriteRule robots.txt robots_disallow.txt [R=301,L]`

Comment: @watkinsmatthewp You could certainly do like you propose except you would need to use !\.com$ as your regular expression (that means that .com must be at the end of the host name).

Comment: OK, and for purely educational purposes, if I do want to catch blocks of numbers up to three digits long in separated blocks (like and ip address), what would the regex be for that?

Comment: ^[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}$  would work for ipv4 addresses